# Cannot get MFC dll functions to run in .net

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, mfc

I'm trying to create a simple MFC DLL, exports its functions and consume in a C# .net project
In the code below I have two methods in the DLL, I have taken the suggestions of the posters to the original question. I'm reposting the current code, I get the error

> {  "Unable to find an entry point named  '_Worker_Create@0'in DLL 'C:\Users\mspath\Documents\MDS_SIMCA\DevSIMCA_Dll\TestDLL\Debug\MFClib.dll'.":""  }

I have used the dumpbin.exe to get the correct mangled names.

### MFC DLL .cpp

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Worker.h"

    Worker::Worker(void)
    {
    }

    Worker::~Worker(void)
    {
    }

    int Worker::GetInteger()
    {
        return 44;
    }

    int Worker::DoMath(int iOne, int iTwo)
    {
        return iOne * iTwo;
    }
```

### MFC DLL .h

class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(void);
    ~Worker(void);

```
static int GetInteger ();
static int DoMath (int iOne, int iTwo);
```

};

### MFCLib.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void * __stdcall Worker_Create()
    {
        return new Worker();
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void  * __stdcall Worker_Destroy(Worker * instance)
    {
        delete instance;
        instance = 0;
        return instance;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Worker_DoMath(Worker * instance, int i, int j)
    {
        return instance->DoMath(i, j);
    }
}
```

### C# .net

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
/*
 *          from dumbin.exe /exports:
 *          
          1    0 00011519 _Worker_Create@0 = @ILT+1300(_Worker_Create@0)
          2    1 00011230 _Worker_Destroy@4 = @ILT+555(_Worker_Destroy@4)
          3    2 000110D2 _Worker_DoMath@12 = @ILT+205(_Worker_DoMath@12)
*/
        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\mspath\\Documents\\MDS_SIMCA\\DevSIMCA_Dll\\TestDLL\\Debug\\MFClib.dll",
                EntryPoint = "_Worker_Create@0",
                ExactSpelling = false,
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public extern static IntPtr Worker_Create();

        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\mspath\\Documents\\MDS_SIMCA\\DevSIMCA_Dll\\TestDLL\\Debug\\MFClib.dll",
                EntryPoint = "_Worker_Destroy@4",
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public extern static IntPtr Worker_Destroy(IntPtr iptr);

        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\mspath\\Documents\\MDS_SIMCA\\DevSIMCA_Dll\\TestDLL\\Debug\\MFClib.dll",
                EntryPoint = "_Worker_DoMath@12",
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public extern static int Worker_DoMath(IntPtr instance, int i, int j);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr instance = Worker_Create();

            int i = Worker_DoMath(instance, 4, 2);

            Worker_Destroy(instance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried using the extren "c", and just use simple name and still same error

Comment: `GetInteger` and `DoMath` are *instance* functions of the class `Worker`, the easiest way around this is to create a non-instance function in the DLL that creates the instance and returns the result, otherwise you have to figure out a way to create an instance of `Worker` and *then* you can run those functions on it. As it stands, they are not entry points in the DLL and can't be individually run.

Comment: you can always use clr project to connect c# with c++.

Comment: @SHR: You are probably referring to C++/CLI. `/clr` is the compiler command line option to compile C++/CLI, not a project type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare external "C-style" functions *outside* of C++ classes.  One way it to just pipe the call to the class:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int DoMath (int iOne, int iTwo)
{
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    int i = worker-> DoMath(iOne, iTwo);
    delete worker;
    return i;
}
```

Or convert your C++ classes to C++/CLI classes and import the library as a *managed* library instead of an *unmanaged* library.

*Disclaimer*: My C++ is rusty so I may be slightly off on the syntax and/or proper memory management.

Comment: You also need to specify the calling convention. Since the managed code in the question is using `CallingConvention.StdCall`, it should be `__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall DoMath(int iOne, int iTwo)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling convention is wrong.  __declspec(dllexport) only makes the function exported, it does not make it have the standard calling convention.  I would add __stdcall or WINAPI to your function signatures so that they are using standard calling.  Your one function works because it has no arguments to pass or to pop off the stack.

Comment: adding __stdcall to the function signatures does not solve the issue. I will try the above suggestion of creating a Worker class object

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand how to get this dll to work. I have taken the suggestion of "pipeing" as D Stanley suggested. I think I misunderstood what he means but I created a method in the MFCLib class to create a Worker object and call the DoMath function. This gives me the same failure.

Comment: extern "C"
{
 __declspec(dllexport) void * __stdcall Worker_Create()
 {
  return new Worker();
 }

 __declspec(dllexport) void  * __stdcall Worker_Destroy(Worker * instance)
 {
  delete instance;
  return instance;
 }

 __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Worker_DoMath(Worker * instance, int i, int j)
 {
  return instance->DoMath(i, j);
 }
}

Comment: code above is in DLL, I try to invoke in the C# code and get "Unable to find an entry point named '_Worker_Create@0' in DLL   uuuughh!